# How are connections checked out and freed in SQLAlchemy when SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE is set?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have application based of flask+sqlalchemy which connects to PostgreSQL. And seems during some network issues connection with insert which occupy lock become stale and further retries get error

```
(psycopg2.errors.LockNotAvailable) canceling statement due to lock timeout\\n
CONTEXT:  while inserting index tuple (10537404,29) in relation
```

I have SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE = 600 and lock was unavailable for 15~16 minutes. I don't get why. In [SQLAlchemy doc](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/pooling.html#setting-pool-recycle) about pool recycle it is said that connection invalidation occurs only during checkout. When checkout is performed if I use `db.session`? And will setting `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout` to 4 min in database help to free this lock earlier?